# Modify database in django

Tags: django, database, save, view

I am a beginner in django. Following is my Attendance Management App.
This is my models.py.

```
from django.db import models

class Subject(models.Model):
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    #attendance = models.ForeignKey(Attendance, on_delete = 
    models.DO_NOTHING)
    attendance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject_name


class Section(models.Model):
    section_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.section_name


class Student(models.Model):
    rollno = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING, 
    default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rollno) + self.name 


class Teacher(models.Model):
    #teacher_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #section_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    #subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.section.section_name+' '+self.subject.subject_name


class TeacherList(models.Model):
    teacher_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    teacher = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.teacher_name
```

The line below is not working in views.py

```
student = models.Student.objects.get(rollno = sroll)
student.section.subject.get(subject_name = 'java').attendance += 1
student.save()
```

This view is called from a template when a button is clicked to add attendance of a student.
The attendance in above code is not modified. Please help me out.

Comment: Is it because in your `class Subject` you have a random line of code "`models.DO_NOTHING)`" that should be commented out?  When you say it doesn't work does it have an error or does it just not save the `student` instance?

Comment: There is no error. But the attendance is not incremented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saving the student, instead of the subject.

```
student = models.Student.objects.get(rollno = sroll)
subject = student.section.subject.get(subject_name='java')
subject.attendance += 1
subject.save()
```

Or, better, do the update directly in one go:

```
student.section.subject.filter(subject_name='java').update(attendance=F('attendance')+1)
```

and there's no need to save at all.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Roseman. But this code incremented attendance of whole class corresponding to subject 'java'. Maybe my model is wrongly designed. Please suggest me something that should work here.

Comment: Well yes, you would need some kind of Attendance model as the through table in a relationship between Student and Subject. But I can't really give a proper answer as I don't understand what your Section model is for.

Comment: Students belong to a Section which may have 5-6 subjects. And each subject is taught by a teacher. Please suggest me relationships between these models so that attendance of each student could be marked for every subject individually.